# Extract pages from PDF with javascript in Acrobat Pro

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to create a script that will extract all pages from a pdf document and name them from the number of the pdf (say the pdfs name is 5047.pdf) and then increment the name for every page of the pdf so it produces 5048.pdf, 5049.pdf etc. However my script doesnt do anything.

```
var filename = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < this.numpages; i++)
this.extractpages

({
nStart: i,
cpath: filename + i + ".pdf"

});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your using to extract pages, but surely you want to do that before your loop.. Or how else will the loop know how many pages. :)

Comment: I copied the above script from ADOBE ACROBAT SDK :-), plz help me correct it if you can.

Comment: could you try this.extractpages(i,i);

Comment: And do this.numPages,  not this.numpages

Comment: Oh, and this.extractPages(i,i);  javascript is case-sensitive.. So I assume Adobe's is too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original link: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/969135

The solution, based on an answer from Adobe's forum:

```
/* Extract Pages to Folder */

var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;

var filename = this.path.replace(re,"");
var lastPage=this.numPages-1;
{
    for ( var i = 0;  i < this.numPages; i++ ) 
    this.extractPages
     ({
        nStart: i,
        nEnd: lastPage,
        cPath : filename + "_page_" + (i+1) + ".pdf"
    });
};
```

Comment: cPath : Number(filename) + (i+1) + ".pdf" makes it increment the filename properly. 5145, 5146, 5147 etc instead of 5145, 51451, 51452 etc.

Comment: It doesnt create one page pdf-files, it creates mult page pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, it was necessary to extract 2 pages in a row:

```js
/* Extract Pages to Folder */

var re = /.*\/|\.pdf$/ig;

var filename = this.path.replace(re,"");
var lastPage=this.numPages-1;
{
    for ( var i = 0;  i < this.numPages; i = i + 2 ) 
    this.extractPages
     ({
        nStart: i,
        nEnd: i + 1,
        cPath : filename + "_page_" + (i+1) + ".pdf"
    });
};
```